# Append string list with int list

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this code I need to send the first string "Computer" and "Networks" to the function of frame_data().The work of this function is to append the received x in l[] and the append the length of the received x in l2[]. Then the output of sender should be like this : 9Computer9Networks.
The problem in the `sender += l2 + l` I got on this error: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`

How can fix the code please?

```
def frame_data(x):
    l = []
    l2 = []
    
    l.append(x)
    FrameLen = len(x)
    l2.append(FrameLen+1)

    sender = ''
    sender += l2 + l
    print(sender)

def split_str(seq, chunk, skip_tail=False):
    lst = []
    if chunk <= len(seq):
        lst.extend([seq[:chunk]])
        lst.extend(split_str(seq[chunk:], chunk, skip_tail))
    elif not skip_tail and seq:
        lst.extend([seq])
    frame_data(lst)

seq = "ComputerNetworks"
split_str(seq, 8)
```

Why this function enter in loop when the input is

frame_data_check("9Computer6Networks")

Comment: Both 'Computer' and 'Networks' happen to be 8-characters long. How would you handle words of varying length?

Comment: by using print(split_str(seq, 6, skip_tail=True))

Comment: Surely, '9Computer6Networks' makes no sense. Isn't the number meant to represent the length of the following sequence of characters?

Comment: Yes, and 6 is not correct len for "Networks"

Comment: `sender` is a string.  `l1` and `l2` are lists.  It makes no sense to append a list to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is unnecessarily complicated.

You can split the string with a simple loop using the *chunk* value as the *step* in a range.

It seems that the *skip_tail* bool is used to indicate that a potential trailing string that is less than the specified length are to be omitted.

EDIT: Added frame_check function

```
def split_str(s: str, n: int, skip_tail=False) -> list[str]:
    rv = [s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s), n)]
    return rv[:-1] if  skip_tail and rv and len(rv[-1]) != n else rv

def frame_data(x: list[str]) -> str:
    return ''.join([f'{len(e)+1}{e}' for e in x])

def frame_check(s: str) -> bool:
    n = -1
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        if s[i].isdecimal():
            k = int(s[i])
            if n < 0:
                n = k
            else:
                n = n * 10 + k
            i += 1
        else:
            if (n := n - 1) <= 0:
                return False
            i += n
            n = -1
    return n < 0

N = 8

for s in 'ComputerNetworks', 'ComputerNetwork':
    for skip in True, False:
        fd = frame_data(split_str(s, N, skip_tail=skip))
        print(f'{skip=}', f'{s=}', f'{N=}', fd)
        assert frame_check(fd)

assert frame_check('9Computer6Networks')
```

**Output:**

```
skip=True s='ComputerNetworks' N=8 9Computer9Networks
skip=False s='ComputerNetworks' N=8 9Computer9Networks
skip=True s='ComputerNetwork' N=8 9Computer
skip=False s='ComputerNetwork' N=8 9Computer8Network
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/DarkKnight/Python/Oct07.py", line 41, in <module>
    assert frame_check('9Computer6Networks')
AssertionError
```